# Helm equals to one of multiple values

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to have a condition that will be considered as "true" if  `.Values.envName` is "dev" + the release namespace name is one of a closed list. otherwise, it should be "false".
Tried the following, but seems like it gets unexpected "false" when I ran it with `.Values.envName` = dev & `.Values.envName` = ns-1:

```yaml
env:
  - name: MY_ENV
    {{- if and (eq .Values.envName "dev") (regexMatch "^(?!^ns-1$)(?!^ns-2$).*$" .Release.Namespace)}}
    value: 'true'
    {{- else }}
    value: 'false'
    {{- end }}
```

A general note - if there is a better way to use `eq` with multiple possible values please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`has`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#has-musthas) to test if some item is in a list; and then you can use [`list`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#lists-and-list-functions) to construct a list of known items.

So for your example, if the test is that `envName` is exactly `dev`, and the namespace is either `ns-1` or `ns-2`, then you can say

```yaml
env:
{{- $isDev := eq .Values.envName "dev" }}
{{- $isNs := list "ns-1" "ns-2" | has .Release.Namespace }}
  - name: MY_ENV
    value: {{ and $isDev $isNs | toString | quote }}
```

You could do this case with a regular expression too.  The start-of-string test `^` and the end-of-string test `$` generally need to be outside parentheses; I wouldn't worry about "non-greedy matches" if you're just trying to determine whether a string matches without extracting things.  Here I might write either of

```
{{- $isNs := regexMatch "^ns-[12]$" .Release.Namespace }}
{{- $isNs := regexMatch "^ns-1|ns-2$" .Release.Namespace }}
```

If you've got an enumerated list of values that don't neatly fall into a regex, using `has` and `list` is probably clearer.